# ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Shared Linux)

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, cublas

I am new to tensorflow and I am working on shared linux (Ubuntu 16.04), it means I don't have root access. Cuda 8.0 and Cudnn 8 are already installed by admin as root. I have installed python 3.5 using anaconda and then installed tensorflow using pip. I have added the cuda-8.0/bin and cuda-8.0/lib64 to PATH and LD_PATH_LIBRARY using following exports.

*export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin"*

*export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64"*

But when I try to run the program it gives the following error.

**ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

However these files exist in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and *nvcc -V* is also working.

Is it even possible to refer to the system installed Cuda and CuDnn ? If yes, can you help to clear the above error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A likely explanation is that your path is not set up correctly. 
Try echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and let us know what you get.

Another explanation is that it is not in that directory. Yes, libcublas.so should normally be in /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 but double check if it is there or another directory by using find.

Comment: echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH gave this.
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 
and find / name="libcublas.so.8.0" gave this.
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcublas.so.8.0